# Dejar campos en blanco con Jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo un fullcalendar; si doy clic en un día se abre un formulario de registro, y tengo un Jquey con unas validaciones, le doy clic al botón agregar y quedan en rojo  los campos que NO ha ingresado datos (Ahí esta bien).

Imagen fullcalendar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen de los campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que pasa es que yo al cerrar el modal y al abrir otro día todos los campos quedan en rojo y pues deberían de estar en blanco normal ¿como solucionaría ese problema?.

Código Jquery.

```
    (function ValidacionesAgregar() {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
            document.getElementById("btnAgregar").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                }
                form.classList.add('was-validated');
            }, false);
        });
    }, false);
})();
```

Comment: Con lo poco que alcanzo a entender, cuando el modal se cierre, necesitas eliminarle a tus input la clase que hace que se pinten de color rojo y así agregarle la otra clase que los deja en blanco.

Comment: Listo solucionado, solo es poner esto en la función de limpiar funcionario y ya. 
$('.was-validated').removeClass();